# Create Access 97 database without dependency on Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, jet

For compatibility with legacy software, I need to create an .mdb database compatible with Access 97 or earlier versions. I cannot use OLEDB, as I cannot rely on Access to be installed. I also do not want to install the Office Connectivity Components.

Are there any third-party libraries that can do that?

Comment: What have you got against the MS Access engine (http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=13255), it is free. From there you can create any version you want (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835033(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but with that it's only possible to create Access databases of type v3.0 and later. When I specify DatabaseTypeEnum.dbVersion30 in the .CreateDatabase call, it works. However, with any lower version (dbVersion20), the call fails with "Could not find installable ISAM". I want to create Version 2.0 or 1.1 databases.

Comment: Deary me, I remember it used to work, I am fairly sure you could do this with the Jet engine, going back to version 1 or 2 from 2010 may be a step too far. You may have the Jet engine, depending on your operating system. If you are on 64 bit, it gets more complicated.

Comment: Ref: http://compgroups.net/comp.databases.ms-access/finding-an-installable-isam/1470461

Comment: This might help http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_createmdb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need Access installed to create `.mdb` files since the Jet engine has been part of Windows forever (since Windows 2000 as part of the MDAC component).

You need to install the ACE drivers only if you plan on creating the newer `.accdb` files (compatible with Access 2007 and above).

To create an empty `.mdb` database, you need to use the *Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security* library `Interop.ADOX.dll`.

You don't need to directly reference it in your VS project, you can use late binding to create the object from whatever version is available on the machine:

```
void Main()
{
    var conStr = GetConnectionString(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\myDatabase.mdb", null, null);
    CreateDb(conStr);
}

//[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
public void CreateDb(string connectionString) {
    Type adoxType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ADOX.Catalog");
    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(adoxType);
    o.GetType().InvokeMember("Create", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, new object[] { connectionString });
    object connection = o.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveConnection", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, o, null);
    if(connection != null)
        connection.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, connection, null);
}

public static string GetConnectionString(string database, string userid, string password) {
    return String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Mode=Share Deny None;data source={0};user id={1};{3}password={2};", 
    database, userid, password, string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) ? string.Empty : "Jet OLEDB:Database ");
}
```

You can use LINQpad to test the code, it works on my machine.
Note that if you try to create the database in folders where you don't have the rights to create files, you will get an unrelated COM exception like:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\myDatabase.mdb'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

To create tables and indexes, etc, you can use [Access' DDL language](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helpcategory14.aspx?CategoryID=CH080204813&lcid=2057&NS=MSACCESS%2EDEV&Version=14&CTT=4) and execute these commands through OleDB, like `command.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE Staff (FirstName CHAR, LastName CHAR)");`

Another, probably simpler solution that could avoid all this code is to simply ship an empty database with your app and just copy that one whenever you need a new database.

To open the database, you can then just use OldDb as usual.

Things to be careful about: make sure you set the target for your App to x86 explicitly; using AnyCPU may get you in trouble on 64 bit machines since you are accessing 32 bit COM components.

Other references:

- [Creating and connecting to a Microsoft Access Database programmatically in C#](http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/create-and-connect-to-a-microsoft-access-database-programmatically-in-c/)
- [Access DDL (Data Definition Language) Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helpcategory14.aspx?CategoryID=CH080204813&lcid=2057&NS=MSACCESS%2EDEV&Version=14&CTT=4)