# Classic ASP : Create MS Access Database ( *.mdb ) with adding tables without MS Access Installed

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic

Please anyone can teach me how to create MS Access Database ( *.mdb ) by coding with Classic ASP?
I have done with below coding and yes *.mdb file is created but it seems not valid *.mdb file. It can't be opened by MS Access software.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<%
    Set Catalog = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    Catalog.Create "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\...\TestDB.mdb"

    sSQL = "CREATE TABLE BridgerSubstitute (" & _
        "Auto_Increment COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY, " & _
        "First_Name varchar(255), " & "Middle_Name varchar(255), " & "Last_Name varchar(255), " &_
        "Entity_Type varchar(255), " & "Address_1 varchar(255), " & "City_1 varchar(255), " & _
        "State_1 varchar(255), " & "Zip_Code_1 varchar(255), " & "Country_1 varchar(255), " & _
        "Address_2 varchar(255), " & "City_2 varchar(255), " & "State_2 varchar(255), " & _
        "Zip_Code_2 varchar(255), " & "Country_2 varchar(255), " & "Aliases varchar(255), " & _
        "Alternate_Spellings varchar(255), " & "Additional_Information varchar(255))"
    
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\...\TestDB.mdb"
    cn.Execute sSQL

  %>
```

Thank you

Comment: ....why are you doing this?

Comment: The problem is you're using the ACE driver, which is for Access 2007+ databases (with an `.accdb` filename extension), but you're confusing it with the JET driver (which is for Access 97 through Access 2003) for databases with the `.mdb` filename extension).

Comment: `CODEPAGE="1252"` <-- Assuming you aren't still using WIndows 98 (_but for all I know you are..._), then your editor is likely saving files as UTF-8, so using an incorrect `CODEPAGE` directive is going to break things as soon as you start using non-7-bit-safe text.

Comment: Using `varchar(255)` for all your columns is suboptimal, also all of your columns are being created as `NULL` by default - you **need** to specify `NOT NULL` otherwise your database will cause you to suffer premature balding.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980602/create-access-97-database-without-dependency-on-access#:~:text=You%20do%20not%20need%20Access%20installed%20to%20create.mdb,newer.accdb%20files%20%28compatible%20with%20Access%202007%20and%20above%29.

Comment: _It can't be opened by MS Access software._ Yes it can, if not using an antique version. Pre Access 2000 can't.

Comment: Mr. Dai, thank you for your reply. I deleted "<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>" and change "*.mdb" to "*.accdb".

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this.  If you want to create a JET (*.mdb) database without MS Access installed.

1. Create your empty database with the 32 bit ODBC manager. (Although I guess your ADOX.Catalog statement is another way of doing this.  I've never seen that object before.)
2. As has been mentioned in the comments, the ACE driver is for ACE (.accdb) rather than JET (.mdb) databases.  MS Access handles both.  The JET OLEDB driver ships with Windows, the ACE driver does not, so I'm guessing that it's a JET Database you want to use as your backend.

The following script worked for me

```
Set conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=C:\path-to\eventsdatabase.mdb;"
    
    conn.execute "drop table Events"
    conn.execute "CREATE TABLE Events(`id` COUNTER NOT NULL,`title` VARCHAR(200),`venue` VARCHAR(200),`starttime` VARCHAR(20), `eventdate` DATETIME,`information` LONGCHAR)"
    conn.execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `EventID` ON Events(`id`)"

    conn.close
 Set conn = Nothing
```

Note that I've specified a different driver to the one you're using, that's the OLEDB driver for JET.  For more info on this visit connectionstrings.com

Note also that the JET driver is 32 bit only.  so you'll have to enable 32 bit applications in your app pool.

The "Drop table" statement is unnecessary, but useful if you're having several goes at creating your table

Obviously you'll need to substitute my field names with your own :)

If this is about not wanting to pay for MS Access there are easier ways of doing this.  For example there's a piece of free software called WinSQL which can connect to any database for which an ODBC connection is available, and it includes a new table wizard.

Comment: Thank you John for your coding.

I did not know that current MS access filename end with *.accdb until Mr. Dai mentioned above. So I am ok with ACE driver by changing *.mdb to *.accdb.

Comment: An important point is that Windows comes with the JET driver, but you need to install the ACE driver.  If you have MS Access on your machine then the driver will have been installed in the installation process, so if you're only running your script on your local machine it won't matter.  If you later upload your code together with your database to a server then you may find the .mdb format more useful because the correct driver will already be installed.  Windows hides file extensions by default.  It's supposed to make it more user friendly. I think it does the opposite :)

Comment: John, I got your point. Thanks for your advice. I will change back to JET and *.mdb